# Is there a way to automate Salesforce configuration programmatically?

Tags: apex, configuration

I'm trying to see how feasible it is to automate configuration like creating user, update profile permission, data addition etc through Apex code or Rest API.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Salesforce Enterprise or Ultimate edition then all of those are possible to automate with Apex and the Rest API to some extent.

Profile permissions are not updateable through Apex, but you can (and should) segregate your different permissions into permission sets instead anyway, and those are assignable through Apex too.

Comment: Profile permissions are updatable through Apex, albeit indirectly. There is a permission set for each profile, which you can identify through the ParentId field. It is that permission set that you can use to update profiles.